# Undefined method in module rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I wrote this module and saved it in lib/Connect.rb

```
module Connect
  def self.fullname
    'Was'
  end
end
```

Next i added in my controller:

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/Connect.rb"
```

Then in my view:

```
<% @employees.each do |employee| %> 
  <%= employee.fullname %>
  <h4><%= link_to "#{employee.vorname} #{employee.nachname}", nutzerverwaltung_path(employee.id) %></h4> 
  <% end %>
```

Somehow now i get the erorr:

```
 undefined method `fullname' for #<Employee:0x37c1e68>
```

What did i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `self` which is for class method.

```
  def fullname
    'Was'
  end
```

require this file at initializers, not controller.

And you also need to include this module in model, for this is going to extend model

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Connect
```